# How to activate a php include by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an admin panel in php.

- My idea is to add a store in the admin panel and it should add the store in database.In the admin panel after submitting it should show the 4 buttons as shown in figure!

for this i have written some html ,but main problem is if i click on show stores it should add a php include and show below like this[image]But the problem is without clicking on show stores the php iclude is default enable.Please help me to include the php file only if i press the show stores button.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Database connection is created with the db AskCoupon.com -->
<?php
//Step1
 if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {

  // Connect to MySQL
  $mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', 'sai123', 'askcoupon.com' );

  // Check our connection
  if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
    die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
  }
  /*New Code added here*/
  $storeName = $_POST['store_name'];

  $check=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from featured_stores where store_name='$storeName'");
    $checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);
   if($checkrows>0){echo "customer exists";}  
else{  
    //insert results from the form input
    $query = "INSERT INTO featured_stores ( store_id, store_name,no_of_coupons,caption ) VALUES ( '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['store_id'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['store_name'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['no_of_coupons'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['caption'])}' )";
    // $insert = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

    mysqli_close($mysqli);
    echo "Store Added";
    }

  };

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Admin Panel</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="../admin_panel" role="button">Insert Another Store</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
     <a class="btn btn-danger" href="../admin_panel" role="button">Insert Another Coupon</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="../Admin_panel/show_stores.php" role="button" onclick="loadThis">Show Stores</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    <button  class="btn btn-success" href="#" role="button" onclick="loadThis">Show Coupons</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function loadThis(){
<?php include'show_stores.php';?>
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also I am including showstores.php file here

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<?php
// 1) connect to the database by mysql_connect()

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "sai123") or die(mysql_error()); 
// 2) than select the database like  mysql_select_db()

mysql_select_db("askcoupon.com") or die(mysql_error()); 
// 3) you need to use mysql_query()

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM featured_stores where 1")  or die(mysql_error());
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Admin Panel</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row well">
<?php
while($row= mysql_fetch_array( $data )){ ?>
    <div class="col-xs- col-sm- col-md-2 col-lg-">
        <?php echo $row['store_id']; ?> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs- col-sm- col-md-4 col-lg-">
        <?php echo $row['store_name'] ?>                                        
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs- col-sm- col-md-3 col-lg-">
        <?php echo $row['no_of_coupons'] ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs- col-sm- col-md-3 col-lg-">
        <?php echo $row['caption'] ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Console Log after answer 1 
[image]

Comment: In your first code you use mysqli* you should also use that in your second code. And maybe you want to delete your password.

Comment: can you explain with a code snippet

Comment: not working @PHPeter

Comment: That was just a comment about your code and telling you maybe want to hide your password. It was not to fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

there are many options, one of which include sending ajax request, in this situation very simple example you can create new include.php file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    


function loadThis() { 
    $.ajax({              
        type: "POST",
        url: "include.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {}
    });
}


/* include.php file */
<?php
include('showstores.php');
?>
```

Comment: url: include.php ,but my file name is show_stores.php

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier is console error

Comment: You should explain your answer, not just post code.

Comment: try again with " between include.php like this: url: "include.php"

Comment: Your code is useless if you don't explain why and what are you doing here with it. When we don't know something, we need details to understand and actually learn it. (Otherwise, if we don't need these explanations, most likely we already knew this answer.)

Comment: @PauliusS. what is include.php i dont have such file

Comment: anyone got the explaination

Comment: @Darren see the log attached above

Comment: @PauliusS. see the log attached to question

Comment: you write function with syntax error need this loadThis() { code... } with brackets

Comment: @PauliusS. explain your last comment

Comment: I see you write function with syntax error without brackets { you write like this loadThis() but need loadThis() { you can just copy from my answer